# My background image not showing in github pages(tailwind css)

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I make a tesla clone with html and taiwind css.It work fine on my live server, but image doesnot show while while deploying it to github page.

The project is given below:
https://github.com/Manikkk3/Tesla-clone-repository

I try changing (./images/...) and (/images/..) but it doesnot work on tailwind.config.js

I try changing (./images/...) and (/images/..) but it doesnot work on tailwind.config.js
I want to display background image.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a direct URL path for your images in tailwind.config.js file

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
    content: ['./*.html'],
    theme: {
        screens: {
            sm: '480px',
            md: '768px',
            lg: '976px',
            ll: '1177px',
            xl: '1440px',
        },
        extend: {
            backgroundImage: {
                Model3: "url('/images/model-3.jpg')",
                ModelY: "url('/images/model-y.jpg')",
                ModelS: "url('/images/model-s.jpg')",
                ModelX: "url('/images/model-x.jpg')",
                SolarPanels: "url('/images/solarpanels.jpg')",
                SolarRoof: "url('/images/roof.jpg')",
                Accessories: "url('/images/accessories.jpg')",
            },
        },
    },
    plugins: [],
}
```

Comment: It doesnot help me.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you have found a solution for this problem yet. I recently faced the same problem and after a lot of searching around I found the solution for this in the [link](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/5504). So I am adding the answer here for anyone who might face a similar problem.

Basically we need to add the path for `url` relative to the css file (after it is generated). Not relative to the `tailwind.config.js` file.

So if the css file is in the build directory like `build/css/main.css` and images are like so: `build/images/model-3.jpg` then the path in url would be:
`"url('../images/model-3.jpg')"`

And the `tailwind.config.js` file would be:

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
    content: ['./*.html'],
    theme: {
        extend: {
            backgroundImage: theme => ({
                'Model3': "url('../images/model-3.jpg')",
                'ModelY': "url('../images/model-y.jpg')",
                'ModelS': "url('../images/model-s.jpg')"
            }),
        },
    },
    plugins: [],
}
```